# Hive Create View as Select (CVAS)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I need help why the the following hive create view as statement:

```
select * from view_1 where user_id is not null  AND rule='مزورة';
```

This returns 1200 rows,

However, when I use it in :

```
Create VIEW view_2 AS select * from view_1 where user_id is not null  AND ruele='مزورة';
```

The table is created but is empty. Please help if you have any suggestions.

Comment: When you create a view, it will create a view object in the database you the need to `SELECT` from the view - like `SELECT * FROM view_2` in your case, that would get you the records..

Comment: View in hive wont create a table or stores data like the traditional database. Only when you you query the view the map reduce execution runs.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. but I said in my post, the view structure gets created, however with empty rows.  I know this because, I can describe view_2 and see all the fields, I then select * from view_2 and it returns 0 rows.  It is almost as though hive is not able to execute the where clause with the arabic term when I use the Create As ... however when I select * from view_1 with the same where clause, 12 rows return.  I need help with a deadline please help if you know about this issue. thanks guys/gals